# Problem in making a Calculator to check validity in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a simple calculator in which you enter 2 numbers and choose your operation and the result is displayed.

I achieved the above mentioned task but I want to design a system by which it is first checked if operation is valid before asking for number input and if the option(operation) chosen is invalid, the user should be asked to choose again.

```
print("Welcome to the Great Calculator")

print("                                     ")

print("Please choose Your Operation")

print("1 Addition")

print("2 Subtraction")

print("3 Multiplication")

print("4 Division")

print("5 Exponent")

choice=int(input("What is your choice?[1,2,3,4,5]: "))

print("                                     ")

while (choice ==1,2,3,4,5):
    n1=int(input("Please enter the First Number- "))

    print("                                     ")

    n2=int(input("Please enter the Second Number- "))

    if (choice==1):
        result=n1 + n2
        print("The Sum is",result)

    elif (choice==2):
        result=n1 - n2
        print("The Difference is",result)

    elif (choice==3):
       result=n1 * n2
       print("The Product is",result)

    elif (choice==4):
       result=n1 / n2
       print("The Quotient is",result)

    elif (choice==5):
       result=n1 ** n2
       print("The Answer is",result)

    else:
       print("Invalid Input")

else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

I am not able to achieve my goal. Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: hint: maybe you need to prompt a new `choice` when it's invalid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the valid choices are numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. First we set the `choice` to 0 in order to make the `choice` invalid and enter the `while` loop, then we ask for `input`. The program is stuck in `while` loop as long as the choice made is invalid (`choice not in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`).

```
choice = 0
while choice not in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    choice=int(input("What is your choice?[1,2,3,4,5]: "))

print('\n')
n1 = int(input("Please enter the First Number- "))
print('\n')
n2 = int(input("Please enter the Second Number- "))

if choice == 1:
    result = n1 + n2
    print("The Sum is %s" % result)

elif choice == 2:
    result = n1 - n2
    print("The Difference is %s" % result)

elif choice == 3:
    result = n1 * n2
    print("The Product is %s " % result)

elif choice == 4:
    result = n1 / n2
    print("The Quotient is %s" % result)

elif choice == 5:
    result = n1 ** n2
    print("The Answer is %s" % result)
```

Also one possible improvement to your script would be to check if inputs are integers before casting them to integers. For example if the input was a letter instead of a number your script would crash.

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Answer extended. Hope this explains it but if you have any more questions feel free to ask:)

Answer (score 0):

The complete working implementation is shown below:

```
print(
    "Welcome to the Great Calculator\n"
    "Please choose Your Operation\n"
    "1 Addition\n"
    "2 Subtraction\n"
    "3 Multiplication\n"
    "4 Division\n"
    "5 Exponent\n"
)

choice = int(input("What is your choice?[1,2,3,4,5]: "))

print("\n")

while choice in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    n1 = int(input("Please enter the First Number- "))
    print("\n")
    n2 = int(input("Please enter the Second Number- "))

    if choice == 1:
        result = n1 + n2
        print("The Sum is %s" % result)

    elif choice == 2:
        result = n1 - n2
        print("The Difference is %s" % result)

    elif choice == 3:
        result = n1 * n2
        print("The Product is %s " % result)

    elif choice == 4:
        result = n1 / n2
        print("The Quotient is %s" % result)

    elif choice == 5:
        result = n1 ** n2
        print("The Answer is %s" % result)

    else:
        print("Invalid Input")

else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Output:

```
>>>python3 test.py 
Welcome to the Great Calculator
Please choose Your Operation
1 Addition
2 Subtraction
3 Multiplication
4 Division
5 Exponent

What is your choice?[1,2,3,4,5]: 2


Please enter the First Number- 5


Please enter the Second Number- 2
The Difference is 3
```

NOTE: I think you should implement an exit option inside the `while` loop or put a `break` after operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot milanbalazs but can you tell how we can write the code so that a loop is made which is exited only when choice is within the specified parameters.If not, then the program should keep asking for the choice.